# Nohup doesn't work when executing script from Jenkins

Tags: linux, command-line, jenkins, nohup

I have bash script which executes following

```
nohup ws --port 8080 &
```

when executing that script directly on remote server and closing connection - process still exists. But when i am using Jenkins "SSH plugin" - process stops after Jenkins closes connection. To execute that script i am using simple command sh scriptName.sh

Comment: I have managed to resolve issue by redirecting nohup output like:
nohup ws --port 8080 >/dev/null 2>&1 &

Answer (score 0):

Best simple solution is to use "at now" instead of "nohup"

In your job jenkins (execute shell) put :

```
set +e #so "at now" will run even if java -jar fails
#Run java app in background
echo "java -jar $(ls | grep *.jar | head -n 1)" | at now + 1 min
```